# Deploying a LightSwitch application as a 2-tier app

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

So I've been playing with LightSwitch a little tonight. Looks pretty slick and for my needs could be what I need.

A few questions I have that maybe the folks here can answer -

1. Deploying the application as a 2-tier app (desktop only). Would the client have to have SQL Serve Express already installed? Or when you build the app does it include SQL for the DB connectivity?
2. Can you sell LightSwitch applications for profit?
3. I know Silverlight is on the Apple platform now, would a 2-tier LightSwitch application work on a Mac?

Comment: You might also post this to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/threads since it's still beta software.  Once it gets up and going I think lightswitch traffic on stackoverflow will increase.

Comment: Chris, I was thinking about that as well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the 2-tier model you would deploy your database somewhere as part of the deployment. So no SQL express is needed on the client. Think of it this way: Tier 1 = GUI+Data Access/Business Rules, Tier 2= SQL
2. Yes, you can.
3. Project Moonlight is what powers Silverlight on Apple and that does not support the Out Of Browser experience needed for a 2 tier app, so no.